# How to fix copied folder name

Tags: vb.net, directory

I have a vb application which copies folders and its subfolder that is working properly. My problem is that it is not copying the correct folder name of the folder being copied.

Like if I copy the folder with this location: C:\Users\Documents\Sample_Folder
The output copied folder name would be "Documents".

C:\Users\Documents\Sample_Folder\Sample_Folder_2
The output copied folder name would be "Sample_Folder".

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCopy.Click
    Dim SourcePath As String = txtBrowse.Text
    Dim DestinationPath As String = "C:\Users\1000258123\Desktop\NEW"

    Dim newDirectory As String =
        System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationPath,
                               Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(SourcePath)))
    If Not (Directory.Exists(newDirectory)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectory)
    End If
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SourcePath, newDirectory)
    MsgBox("Copy Successful")

End Sub
```

Comment: _"My problem is that it is not copying the correct folder name of the folder being copied."_ - from my perspective it is. if you want to use the parent folder name of the folder being copied, you'll have to write code to extract the parent folder name. I believe you can use [Directory.GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: You don't need to call `Path.GetDirectoryName` if the `SourcePath` _is_ already a directory path. Just use `Path.GetFileName(SourcePath)` and combine it with the destination path _as you're already doing_, and you should be good to go.